# How to populate a hashmap through iteration or recursion in clojure?

Tags: clojure

I am new to clojure and can't really wrap my head around adding to a hashmap without using a typical for loop like other languages would. For example, if I have the following code segment:

```
(def empty-hashmap {})
(def big-hashmap (assoc empty-hashmap 1 2))
```

how would I iterate through and add 300 separate elements to the big hashmap? In this case I want my code to look something like

```
(def empty-hashmap {})
(def big-hashmap (assoc empty-hashmap n (abundance n)))
```

where n is the numbers 1 to 300 and it populates 300 elements into the big hashmap.

Answer (score 3):

As Alan Thompson says, `reduce` is the general purpose tool for iterating over a sequence and accumulating a result. But if you need to make many "independent" changes, as here you associate keys in a map with values that don't depend on anything but the key, there are better tools. `map` is the general purpose tool for producing a new sequence based on an old one, and `into` is for turning sequences into maps. So, you can write

```
(into {}
      (map (fn [n] [n (abundance n)])
           (range 1 301)))
```

Note that `(fn [n] [n (abundance n)])` could also be written `(juxt identity abundance)`, though it's up to you which you find clearer.

Personally I don't like writing `(map (fn [n] ...))` - usually if you need a (one-argument) lambda, `for` is a better tool than `map`. The `into`/`for` pairing is very common for tasks like this:

```
(into {}
      (for [n (range 1 301)]
        [n (abundance n)]))
```

I would not at all recommend using an `atom` just for a "more imperative feel". There are good times to use an atom, but beginners don't run into them super quickly, and this isn't one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add a `reduce` code example to @amalloy's answer:

```
  (let [keys [:a :b :c :d :e :f :g]
        vals [1  2  3  4  5  6  7]]
      (map vector keys vals))

  => ([:a 1] [:b 2] [:c 3] [:d 4] [:e 5] [:f 6] [:g 7])

  
  (let [keys [:a :b :c :d :e :f :g]
        vals [1  2  3  4  5  6  7]]
    (reduce
      (fn [a [k v]] (assoc a k v))
      {}
      (map vector keys vals)))
  => {:a 1, :b 2, :c 3, :d 4, :e 5, :f 6, :g 7}
```

This uses [`reduce`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/reduce) with an "accumulator function". For each iteration, the function is called with the old value of the map and a new key-value pair. It assoc's in the new value and returns a new map with an extra key-value pair. The initial value is provided as the second argument to `reduce` (the `{}` empty map).

Answer (score -2):

Reduce is a good option here, starting from [my favorite template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template):

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core tupelo.test))

(verify
  (let [result (reduce  (fn [accum item]
                          (assoc accum item (str "item " item)))
                 {} ; initial empty map
                 (range 5)) ; list of items to add
                 ]
    (is= result
      {0 "item 0"
       1 "item 1"
       2 "item 2"
       3 "item 3"
       4 "item 4"})))
```

If you want a more imperative-style solution, you can always accumulate the result into an atom:

```
(verify
  (let [accum (atom {})]
    (doseq [idx (range 5)]
      (swap! accum
        #(assoc % idx (str "item " idx))))
    (is= @accum
      {0 "item 0"
       1 "item 1"
       2 "item 2"
       3 "item 3"
       4 "item 4"})))
```

Comment: `reduce` does not use an atom internally. What makes you think it does?

Comment: Yeah, IReduce is overkill to include here, so removed the comment.

Comment: I'm not aware of an implementation of IReduce that uses an atom, though I could certainly believe one exists. Do you have a pointer?

Comment: No, it is all pure Java with a mutable variable. I was already looking up the details when you posted the first comment (beat me to the punch again!).  Here is the source for `IPersistentVector.java`:  https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/APersistentVector.java#L502

Comment: Ah, sure, in Java you don't really have a choice. I don't think I'd compare that to an atom, or even call it mutable (though I agree, of course, the local is being reassigned). It's just Java's way of writing a `loop`.